# Given a bijection $f: A \to B$,then show that $\forall g \subseteq f \subseteq A \times B:g$ is a bijection.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Given a bijection $f: A \to B$,then show that  $\forall g \subseteq f \subseteq A \times B:g$ is a bijection.

---

If $P$ is a property for which the elements  of $f$ satisfy then for every element $(a,b) \in g$ it's clear from the definition of $\subseteq$ that  $(a,b) \in f$ and so such elements  of $g$ satisfy the property $P$.

This is what I know, but does there exist a better way to show that $g$ is a bijection?

Comment: I don’t think this is an acceptable proof that $g$ is a bijection. Because $f$ is a bijection, you know that it satisfies the property that “for all $b\in B$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $(a,b)\in f$.” So..., if you pick $b$ in the range of $g$, the property guarantees the existence of an $(a,b)\in f$; but you need it to be **in $g$**, not merely in $f$. So the fact that it happens in $f$ doesn’t immediately help you. You don’t need “a better way” to show $g$ is bijection, you need to actually *show* $g$ is a bijection; you haven’t so far.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'property' here; I think that angle of reasoning is a little bit off-target. You should be a bit careful: $g$ will _not_ be a bijection $A\mapsto B$. Instead, you have to figure out what set(s) it will be a bijection on.

Comment: P is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

The statement you want to prove is, in itself, extremely questionable (some would say "false"). First, it is clear that if $f\subseteq A\times B$ is a function $A\to B$ and $g\subsetneq f$, then $g$ **isn't** a function $A\to B$ because $\operatorname{dom}g\subsetneq A$.

Secondly, even if we want to inspect what $g:\operatorname{dom}g\to B$ is, it is a fact that if $f$ is an injective function $A\to B$ and $g\subsetneq f$, then $g[\operatorname{dom} g]\subsetneq f[A]$. Therefore it is impossible for $g$ to be surjective onto $B$.

After peeling off all impossibilities, the ony thing that is possible to prove is that if $f:A\to B$ is a bijection and $g\subseteq f$, then $g:\operatorname{dom} g\to \operatorname{range}g$ is bijective, which is quite a weird way to phrase the fact that $g:\operatorname{dom}g\to B$ is injective.